# Android Top and Bottom menu

Tags: android, menu, menubar

I am new in Android and i don't have much programming knowledge. I want to create top and bottom menus for my android app. i have attached a sample image. Please someone help me

[image]

Comment: you can deisgn it through your xml file. You have to create two layouts inside a parent layout one for top and another one for bottom then add buttons and other required widget to each layout accordingly

Comment: Simplest way is to have two linear layouts and align one to top and one to bottom. Then fit your buttons etc within that.

Comment: thanks for the replay Vaibhav Agarwal and Adam Short . i will try it and update here

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities of how you can achieve something like that:

1) Use a split `ActionBar` ([more information on the `ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar))

2) You can define it yourself inside an XML-layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Your page-content can go here -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Design two custom layout xml one for top menu bar and one for bottom menu bar. And include these  xml file in your main xml. Then call the button in custom xml same as calling from main xml in the java file.